# Error - DNS failed to connect to endpoint of AWS when connecting esp32

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloud, esp32, arduino-ide

I am trying to connect esp32 to AWS IoT Core using Arduino IDE platform. I am getting an error - DNS failed to connect to endpoint of AWS. Failed, rc =-2.

I am including the "connection of esp32 to AWS" part of code:

```
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> // Arduino PubSubClient library

// Initialize AWS IoT Core parameters
const char* awsEndpoint = "endpoint"; // Your AWS IoT Core endpoint
const char* awsThingName = "xyz";  // Your IoT Thing name
const char* awsClientId = "SWIOT";    // Client ID
const char* awsTopic = "silowise/sub";   // MQTT Topic

WiFiClientSecure Wificlient;
PubSubClient mqtt(Wificlient);

// Add your AWS IoT Core certificate and private key content here
const char* root_ca = R"(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)";

const char* your_cert = R"(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)";

const char* your_private_key = R"(
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
)";

WiFiMulti WIFI;
#define WIFI_SSID "R5"
#define WIFI_PASS "silowise12345"

void connectToAWS() {
    Serial.println("Connecting to AWS...");
    while (!mqtt.connect(awsClientId)) {
        Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
        Serial.print(mqtt.state());
        Serial.println(" Retrying in 5 seconds");
        delay(5000);
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to AWS");
}
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WIFI.addAP(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
    // Connect to AWS IoT Core
    Wificlient.setCACert(root_ca);
    Wificlient.setCertificate(your_cert);
    Wificlient.setPrivateKey(your_private_key);
    mqtt.setServer(awsEndpoint, 8883);
    connectToAWS();
}

void loop() {
    if (WIFI.run() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    // Read sensor data
    // Publish sensor data to AWS IoT Core
        if (mqtt.connected()) {
            String payload = "{"
                "\"temperature\":" + String(sensTemp) + ","
                "\"humidity\":" + String(sensMoist) + ","
                "\"co2\":" + String(CO2) + ","
                "\"weight\":" + String(force_sensor) +
                "}";
            mqtt.publish(awsTopic, payload.c_str());
        } else {
            connectToAWS();
        }
    }
}
```

I created the things in AWS. Created all the necessary policies and attached all the certificates. My code is running properly and all my sensors are fetching the data. I expected the code to give me a connection between my esp32 and AWS IoT Core. But it is throwing network errors. I am using Mumbai region in AWS. What might possibly be the reason for this error ? How to resolve it ?

Answer (score -1):

As per your verification, endpoint and all the certs are correct. so I would recommend that:

1. You use `WiFi.h` only instead of `MultiWiFi.h` as the MultiWiFi is used for connecting with the router of strongest WiFi Signals
2. If you want to use any of the above mentioned libraries, then please ensure that your device stays `connected` to the respective `WiFi` during connecting with AWS.
3. You also have to ensure that your router is `not blocking outbound traffic` or it should not have any `proxy server` configured in it.
4. You can also try using the IP address directly to see if the issue is related to DNS resolution. `mqtt.setServer(IPAddress(XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX), 8883);`

Comment: I made the above mentioned changes and now it is throwing these errors: [ 12578][E][ssl_client.cpp:129] start_ssl_client(): socket error on fd 48, errno: 104, "Connection reset by peer"
 [ 12582][E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:144] connect(): start_ssl_client: -1
 Failed, rc=-2 Retrying in 5 seconds

Comment: SSL - A fatal alert message was received from our peer

Comment: your router is not allowing the aws traffic through it. check your router settings.